# HTML select "Done" label not showing on Ionic for iOS

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, safari, ionic-framework

I am building an iOS-app using the Ionic-framework. When I use select-elements, I do not get the header with the label "Done" when selecting items in the menu on iOS-native. However it will show up when I use the app in iOS/Safari. Screenshots and code attached. Any input/solutions on this would be much appreciated.

**Screenshots:**

**iOS Safari Screenshot**
[image: iOS Safari Screenshot]

**iOS Native/Ionic Screenshot**
[image: iOS Native/Ionic Screenshot]

**Markup**

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
        Bostadstyp
    </div>
    <select ng-change="addParam('objectType', selectedHouseType)" ng-model="selectedHouseType" ng-options="houseType.id as houseType.label for houseType in houseTypes"></select>
</label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML SELECT on iOS Chrome doesn't show "Done" option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960376/html-select-on-ios-chrome-doesnt-show-done-option)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ionic app contains a default code in app.js who hide the keyboard acessory bar, you need to comment this following line: cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

Getting something like this:

```
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  //cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that! Really appreciated. Why would I want to use it in the first place?

Comment: Nice! I really don't know why the Ionic's project came with this hide function active.

Comment: In my experience, commenting it did not cut it. I had to change the `true` to `false` and run it that way. So that bloody problems goes away only when you run the following code; cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);

Answer (score 3):

Regarding @emccracken's comment, [according to the Ionic Team the reason for hideKeyboardAccessoryBar is](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-mandatory-install-the-ionic-keyboard-plugin/7173/16?u=patrickmcd) "because native apps seldom have an accessary bar. It's a dead give away that an app is built with web tech and isn't native."

You can show and hide the accessory bar on demand which is [explained a bit here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/handling-select-options-and-ios-keyboards/17210/5?u=patrickmcd). Taking the $timeouts out of the directive worked better for me. Here's what mine looks like.

```
.directive('select', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('focus', function(e) {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          // console.log("show bar (hide = false)");
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
        }
      });
      element.bind('blur', function(e) {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          // console.log("hide bar (hide = true)");
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: This no longer works as of the last 2 months.  Ionic's keyboard plugin overrides your change after you make it, so you are either stuck with an accessory bar 100% of the time, or without an accessory bar 100% of the time.  It's really kind of stupid.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this issue, my case was a keyboard plugin conflict between 
 **cordova-plugin-keyboard** and **cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard**.

So check on **config.xml** to see if you have more than one plugin and if so remove with:

```
cordova plugin remove [plugin-name]
```

then install proper plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/

Then you will be able to use cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If using Ionic capacitor and facing these issues, none of the fixes here will work.
According to [Capacitor discussions](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/discussions/3478), this is a side effect of the `Keyboard` plugin. Can be fixed by doing:

```
import {Keyboard} from "@capacitor/keyboard";

...

Keyboard.setAccessoryBarVisible({isVisible: true});
```